# RelativeLayout.setLayoutParams causes viewholder pattern to crash

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Depending on the screen size I would like to dynamically set the height of a RelativeLayout. Another method would be to use setMinimumHeight() but I still wonder why this is crashing.

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.question_row_inflater, null);
            vh = new ViewHolder(); // will store references to views
            vh.answerBlock = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerBlock);
            convertView.setTag(vh); // store vh away
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        int height = mRes.getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        // workaround for small screens
        if (height < 490) 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 30);
            vh.answerBlock.setLayoutParams(par);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

This is the classcast exception: [image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/answerBlock"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answerText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the class cast exception because you are calling `vh.answerBlock.setLayoutParams(params);` This sets the parameters on the *parent*  `ViewGroup` (see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)).

So I can surmise that the *answerBlock* `RelativeLayout` is a child of a `LinearLayout` (also the stacktrace is telltale).

The solution (to the exception at least) is to use the `LayoutParams` that match the view's parent.